# How to install wine from the terminal in linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-mint, wine

I'm installing wine from the terminal in Linux Mint 15 (Cinnamon). Here is the command I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

When it gets to 100%, it shows this. I tried pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but it did not work:

[image: wine_thing]

thanks in advance.

Comment: ...and how exactly is this a problem for you? Did you try hitting the Ok button with Enter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select `OK` and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> :)